# What decoder_input_ids should be for sequence-to-sequence Transformer model?

Tags: nlp, huggingface-transformers

I use the HuggingFace's Transformers library for building a **sequence-to-sequence model** based on BART and T5. I carefully read the documentation and the research paper and I can't find what the input to the decoder (decoder_input_ids) should be for sequence-to-sequence tasks.

Should decoder input for both models (BART and T5) be same as lm_labels (output of the LM head) or should it be same as input_ids (input to the encoder)?

Comment: The decoder_input_ids are the labels (i.e. the target) [training documentation](https://huggingface.co/transformers/model_doc/t5.html#training) from huggingface.

Answer (score 1):

The decoder_input_ids (optional) corresponds to labels, and labels are the preferred way to provide decoder_input_ids.
https://huggingface.co/transformers/glossary.html#decoder-input-ids

This is because internally if decoder_input_ids are None, they will be derived by shifting labels to the right, so you don't have to do the shifting yourself.